# How to use linux to split a file into several files with different lines?

Tags: linux, split

I want to use linux command lines to split a file into several files **which will have different lines**. How can I make it?

E.g. Suppose a file with 1000 lines, how can I split **first 600 lines** into **file1**, and **remaining 400 lines** into **file2**? I know *split* can split a big file by same lines, but I don't know wheather I can still use it here.

I'll highly appreciated If anyone could help me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For your example if you use

```
split FILE --lines=600
```

The last 400 lines will end up in the last fragment.

If you want to do arbitrary splits I'd suggest combining `head` and `tail`.

```
# e.g. get the 300 lines following line 250
tail  -n +250  FILE | head -n 300
```

Comment: Repeatedly running `head | tail` on the same file is rather inefficient. A simple `sed` script only needs one pass. `sed -e '1,12wonefile' -e '13,17wanother' -e '18,$wetc'` writes the first 12 lines to one file, the next five to another, and the remainder to a third. (Some dialectal variation between platforms - see the local man page for what exactly the syntax looks like on your box.)